# PHP : to display only new row of a table in bold and rest without any formating (data will be entered by the user)

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to display every new row in bold  that will be stored in database in php and and then display it. Only the new row should be bold. Here's what I did

```
<?php
//connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "resultdb"; //my database name


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

?>

<?php

$name=$_POST['name'];
$roll=$_POST['roll'];
$m1=$_POST['m1'];
$m2=$_POST['m2'];
$m3=$_POST['m3'];

//ISNERT DATA INTO TADABASE
$sql="INSERT INTO markstb(name,rollno,sub1,sub2,sub3) VALUES('$name','$roll','$m1','$m2','$m3')";

if($conn->query($sql)===true)
{
    //ketp id column in DB to auto_increment
    $last_id=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    echo " NEW RECORD INSERTED"."<br>";
    if($last_id>0)
    {
        $sql3="SELECT * FROM markstb WHERE id='$last_id'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql3);
        echo "<table border='2'  bordercolor='black' ";
        echo"<tr><td>NAME</td><td>ROLLNO</td><td>SUB1</td><td>SUB2</td><td>SUB3</td></tr>";
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo"<tr><td><b>".$row['name']."</td><td><b>".$row['rollno']."</td><td><b>".$row['sub1']."</td>"
        ."<td><b>".$row['sub2']."</td><td><b>".$row['sub3']."</td>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"check last_id";
    }
    echo "<br><br><br><br>";

}
else
{
    echo "ERROR".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
}

//RETRIVE DATA FROM DATABASE

$sql2="SELECT * FROM  markstb ORDER BY name";
//$result=$conn->query($sq2);
$result = $conn->query($sql2);
echo "<table border='2'  bordercolor='black' ";
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo"<tr><td>NAME</td><td>ROLLNO</td><td>SUB1</td><td>SUB2</td><td>SUB3</td></tr>";
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {

        echo"<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['rollno']."</td><td>".$row['sub1']."</td>"
        ."<td>".$row['sub2']."</td><td>".$row['sub3']."</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo" 0 rows";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

In above program I have ony fetched the row which is new and made it bold
but I have to show all data that is in database and make only row bold which is new, which is entered by the user.

Comment: sorry for that all-caps :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last while loop you could try:

```
          if($row['id'] == $last_id){
              //echo "your row that is                    
               //bold 
             }else{
              // echo you regular row
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing out the data, you can do this type of thing inside of the echo statement:

```
echo "<tr" . $last_id === (int) $row['id] ? . ' class="bold"' : null; . "><td>...";
```

So that means, when you are printing the  tag, you are checking if the row id matches the last id, if so you are additionally printing a html class of "bold".

Of course, it's up to you to use css to target this selector and actually make it bold.

That is called the 'ternary if'. It looks like this:

```
condition ? do this if true : do this if false;
```